# Solution of $\dot{V} (t)\le -\alpha V(t)-\beta $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anybody know the solution of $\dot{V} (t)\le -\alpha V(t)-\beta $ in terms of some inequalities?

Where $V(t)\ge 0$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are positive constants; the overdot means the time derivative.

Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with using integrating factors?

Comment: Please guys, somebody helps me. it cannot be solved by integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\bigl(e^{\alpha t}V(t)\bigr)\le-\beta\,e^{\alpha t}.
$$
Integrate between $0$ and $t$ to get
$$
e^{\alpha t}V(t)-V(0)\le-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\bigl(e^{\alpha t}-1\bigr)
$$
and
$$
V(t)\le (V(0)+\frac{\beta}{\alpha})e^{-\alpha t}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.
$$
Observe that eventually $V$ will become negative.

Comment: That's it, thanks.